# Populate combobox in VBA via any api or something else

Tags: vba

```
Set FontList = Application.CommandBars("Formatting").FindControl(ID:=1728)

'   If Font control is missing, create a temp CommandBar
If FontList Is Nothing Then
    Set Tempbar = Application.CommandBars.Add
    Set FontList = Tempbar.Controls.Add(ID:=1728)
End If

'   Put the fonts into column A
'Range("A:A").ClearContents
For i = 0 To FontList.ListCount - 1
   cbmFontList.value = FontList.List(i + 1)
Next i

'   Delete temp CommandBar if it exists
On Error Resume Next
Tempbar.Delete
```

This doesn't work. I want to fill a combobox on a userform and avoid hard-coded entries.

Comment: Are you asking *How do I add an item to a combobox?*, or are you really asking *How do I enumerate the installed fonts at runtime?*. They're hardly the same thing.

Comment: yess u r right my question is..How do I enumerate the installed fonts at runtime? in my code.. as want to use install font in my vba code in combobox

Answer (score 0):

Use the `AddItem()` function to add items to a combo box. Assuming your form object is named `UserForm1`:

```
' Clear any entries...
UserForm1.cmbFontList.Clear

' Add each font...
For i = 1 To FontList.ListCount
   UserForm1.cbmFontList.AddItem FontList.List(i)
Next i

' Show the form...
UserForm1.Show
```

Comment: thanks bond for edit my question but i want to know about any windows  API to fill my combobox. with all font name..

Comment: @NeerajSinghChouhan: You don't need the Windows API to add items to a combobox; you use it's  `AddItem` method as Bond has indicated. I think you're asking the wrong question. See my comment to your question above.